# Error when running docker container "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to dockerize a simple Spring Boot Application, built with Maven.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

When I run the .jar without the container (`java -jar target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`), everything works fine and the app is running.

Now I create the container with `docker build -t company/backend .`

But when I try to run the docker container with `docker run -p 8080:8080 company/backend` the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at de.company.backend.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

It seems like docker does not find the main class, even though it is defined in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainClass>de.elbdev.backend.Application</mainClass>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Main Class:**

```
package de.company.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: error is `        at de.elbdev.backend.Application.main(Application.java:10)` so it does find the class. the dependency is missing

Comment: How do you build the Dockerfile? Do you use the `com.spotify::dockerfile-maven-plugin` plugin?

Comment: @Nikolas It is a file in my root folder, I wrote "by myself". Im not using the dockerfile-maven-plugin. emrhzc: okay, but how do I fix that? I thought thats why I installed the maven-dependency-plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pom.xml, the `copy-dependencies` goal is specified at the `install` phase : too late the package of the jar was already done.

> I am trying to dockerize a simple Spring Boot Application, built with
>   Maven.

You don't need to declare any plugin to create a fat jar with spring boot that could be run by a docker container.
Declaring these plugins is error prone (and should be used only in corner cases) while [the `repackage` goal of the spring boot maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) attached by default to the package phase of maven will create for you the fat jar :

> Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed
>   from the command line using java -jar

Juste remove these plugins declarations and execute `mvn clean package` and it should be good.

Side note :

> FROM openjdk:latest

Don't use `latest` as image version but favor a specific version of the image othewhise you could have bad surprises.  As you use JDK 8, you could specify a JRE or a JDK 8 such as :  `FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine`.

Comment: I've ran into the same problem with Spring Boot (parent) 2.3.7.RELEASE. I removed the very same plugins mentioned by OP, ran `mvn clean package` but now I'm back to the `no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar` error. Consider my Dockerfile equal to the OP's as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.

you need to add plugin in your pom.xml.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If you input as above, it works normally.

and check MANIFEST.MF (in .jar file)

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher   
Start-Class: {your main class}
```