# Docker error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, classnotfoundexception

My maven-spring boot project runs fine when I do so outside of Docker. But once I dockerize it I get an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when I try to run it. Searching this problem I'm told you need to make sure you have the spring-boot-maven-plugin in your plugin management and plugins inside pom.xml, and to include the main class therein. I've done this but the problem persists. My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 as builder
RUN mkdir -p /home/maven
COPY src /home/maven/
COPY chg.json /home/maven/
COPY manifest-QA.yml /home/maven/
COPY manifest-za.yml /home/maven/
COPY manifest-zb.yml /home/maven/
COPY pom.xml /home/maven/
COPY service-account.json /home/maven/
COPY sonar-project.properties /home/maven/
COPY checkLocksmith.sh /home/maven/
COPY buildConfig.json /home/maven/
COPY settings.xml /home/maven/
WORKDIR /home/maven
RUN mvn -s ./settings.xml clean package
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /home/maven
COPY --from=builder /home/maven/target/Program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be same as that of below answer. Please look into it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548934/error-when-running-docker-container-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Looking good to me 
You can check the size of the jar file. When everything is built correctly by the spring maven plugin this should be a fat jar with ~30MB.

Comment: Please edit to put more of the stacktrace, so we know what it was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be with my Dockerfile. This is what I changed it to

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 as builder
WORKDIR /home/maven
COPY src src
COPY ./*.json .
COPY ./*.yml .
COPY ./*.xml .
COPY ./*.sh .

RUN mvn -s ./settings.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:17-oracle
EXPOSE 8088
WORKDIR /home/maven
COPY --from=builder /home/maven/target/Program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: And what did this fix?

Comment: After changing this I was able to access the main class when running the jar file, I no longer received the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your docker file with:

FROM maven:3.8.4 AS maven

WORKDIR /home/maven

COPY . /home/maven

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk17:alpine-jre

ARG JAR_FILE=Program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

WORKDIR /home/maven

COPY --from=maven /home/maven/app/target/${JAR_FILE} /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]